# Sending parameterized data to server-side (ASP.NET) using jQuery, working with $.post but not using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using `jQuery` to store some data in my database. I am using an `MVC 5` application (`ASP.NET`).

The data being send is a **id** `int` parameter and a array of data objects.
When using `$.post` for sending the data to the server-side all seems to be working, however when using the `$.ajax` variant, I get an error about a null parameter which is not optional.

This has probably something to do with the options I am setting in my ajax call, though I am not a JQuery or Javascript expert so I am not entirely sure.

**The 2 calls:**

**Working:**

```
   $.post("/Projects/InventorySaveChanges", { projectId: _projectId, data: JSON.stringify(data)}, function (data) {
       if (data.Result) {
           // Success code
       }
       else {
           // Error code
       }
   }).error(function (a, b) {
       // Error code
   });
```

**Not working:**

```
    var obj = {};
    obj.projectId = _projectId;
    obj.data = JSON.stringify(data);


    $.ajax({
        url: '/Projects/InventorySaveChanges',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: obj,
        success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
            // Success code
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, status, msg) {
            // Error code
        }
    });
```

**The MVC controller endpoint:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult InventorySaveChanges(int projectId, string data) 
 {
    // .. Handle data
 }
```

Using the `ajax` call like this is actually an additional question, besides the current data I also want to store files to the server. The files are being stored in a jQuery variable as follow:

```
var _roomFileUploads = new FormData(); 
var file = $('#addPictureFile')[0].files[0];
_roomFileUploads.append(fileName + "|" + _editingRoom.Id, file);
```

At first I tried to send the files as parameters in the `$.post` function:

```
$.post("/Projects/InventorySaveChanges", { projectId: _projectId, data: JSON.stringify(data), fileUpload: _roomFileUploads }, function (data) {
    if (data.Result) {
        // Success code
    }
    else {
        // Error code
    }
}).error(function (a, b) {
    // Error code
});
```

**MVC Endpoint:**

```
public ActionResult InventorySaveChanges(int projectId, string data, List<IFormFile> fileUpload = null)
{
   // Handle data..
}
```

**The `IFormFile` interface:**

```
public interface IFormFile
{
    string ContentType { get; }
    string ContentDisposition { get; }
    NameValueCollection Headers { get; }
    long Length { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string FileName { get; }
    Stream OpenReadStream();
    void CopyTo(Stream target);
    Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

The above gives me the following error (when adding the fields as parameter to my endpoint):

[image]

Though, I am not sure if this is the way to go to post the files to the server-side. I am building on top of old code which I am trying to keep (mainly) intact, that is why I am trying to send the files as a parameter. Perhaps there is also a way to include the files in the data array object? 
Or should I append all the parameter data to the `_roomFileUploads = new FormData()` variable as well and handle it with `Request.Form` on the server-side?

Comment: Do you need to upload multiple files or single file?

Comment: Data is now being stored in an array, so each record is pushed to an array, one record can have 1 file, but because all records are stored in a array there are multiple files (records) stored to the database at once. So the data variable contains rooms which is an array, each room has 1 file.
The data variable used to consist only of text data so it was never a problem, though now it is giving issues because files are added (stored) as well.

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Not yet, will get back to you once I have implemented it! Thank you.

Comment: It is working, thank you! Had to make one small adjustment since I am using .NET 4.x instead of .Net core: `IEnumerable<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload` instead of `List<IFormFile>`

Comment: I thought you were using .Net Core. and your first call isn't working cause you are providing JSON data and `processData` and `contentType` is false in the `$.ajax` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The Code is modified for multiple files.

```
var obj= new FormData();
obj.append("projectId", 1);
obj.append("data", data);

for (var i = 0; i < $('#file')[0].files.length; i++) {
     model.append("fileUpload", $('#file')[0].files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/Projects/InventorySaveChanges',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: obj,
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
        // Success code
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, status, msg) {
        // Error code
    }
});
```

Controller Code.

```
public ActionResult InventorySaveChanges(int projectId, string data, List<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload = null)
```